How can damage be quantified in a game-agnostic way?
We're all familiar with the usual pattern in games where players have "100 health", which is typically meant to represent an abstract percentage. Or, some games may use different numbers.
This bothers me because it's highly arbitrary. 100 whats? What are the units? This means that every weapon in the game needs to have another arbitrary quantity set on it for how much should be subtracted from the player's health when they are impacted by a bullet shot from a gun, a swing of a sword, etc.
However, there are some quantities that can be measured. A bullet's kinetic energy could be calculated using a formula such as 0.5 * mass * velocity * velocity. The question is then, how does this energy correspond to damage in the body?
Is there a way to quantify the damage to a human body? How can we measure the amount of trauma induced by a character being smacked with a hammer, or being sliced with a knife, or having bullets pass through their body? For the sake of keeping this simple, let's assume only regular-sized humans and assume that the body is a uniform mass of human-meat, changing the damage based on impact area (ex: headshots) can be separate from this quantifiable measurement of damage a weapon does to meat.

This could potentially get some great answers as well from the world building stack exchange

I always thought damage and numbers were done to make the logic more understandable. At a similair note, It's also odd how a character or enemy is usually fully capable of all actions even with only a sliver of health left.

If you want to get more granular, it might be worth taking a look at Dwarf Fortress. Rather than treating health as a single number, it tracks the status of many different limbs/organs/tissues separately, so it can model injury to one part giving a character restricted capabilities.

In most games the damage number will be determined in such a way that it makes the game fun to play. But most physics engines are able to tell you the force of an impact, which is based on speed and mass, and surface of the impact.

I am not sure that it is really useful/applicable to assign a REALISTIC number to games, for a few reasons: Firstly if damage is important to the mechanics of the game, its likely one of the key levers for balancing the game is going to be damage done by various weapons, secondly IRL people have taken fatal wounds and still been somewhat functional for a period of time, in the timespans of a game that mechanism may not be that useful. Finally they are real world factors (fear, pain) that would accompany a wound, those are probably going to be difficult to simulate ACCURATELY in a game.

@DavidT To clarify, I am not making a game. I am trying to make a game-agnostic asset standard to allow for things like guns and characters to be transferred cross-game in an objective way, or made in a tool like Blender and imported into the game. Each implementation can scale the values provided by the assets as needed, but I want an objective baseline.

@DavidT I think that's worth posting as a "frame challenge" answer. There is such diversity in different games' damage models - and the corresponding balancing nuances that come with them - that I think making a principled inter-operable standard as OP seems to be describing is a project doomed to failure. Any scale you choose will necessarily have arbitrary choices, so you might as well make a very simple arbitrary choice like "damage is measured in units of 'centi-human-lethality', where 100 cHL = instant death to an average unarmored human adult" and carry on with the rest of your project.

The typical most powerful female mmo armor is the one that covers the least parts of the body. Trying to apply logic is hard, trying to transfer ingame logic from one to another game is doomed to fail.

There are already good answers to the question, but the question is based on confusing games with simulations. Games have some simulation aspects - some more, some less - because those help us understand the game more easily. But a game's #1 goal is fun and everything else needs to fall in line.

For example, having the player's max health be 26.7 because that's scientifically more correct is not more fun for anybody. Making the player in Halo unable to walk (but not dead) because you only hit them in the legs gravely changes the game mechanics to something the current players won't enjoy. Making Mario unable to jump over bullets because that's unrealistic is not more fun.

@RaphaelSchmitz The game UI can display the health as a percentage, regardless of what the underlying unit is.

Are you aware that "percent" is short for Latin "per centum"? "40% health" literally just means "40 out of a 100 health". "100 health" being the thing that bothered you.

@RaphaelSchmitz No, perhaps you need to re-read the question. The problem isn't the existence of a percentage, the problem is there being no underlying backing unit. If a car engine is 250 horsepower, there is no problem with a user interface displaying its usage at 40%, but under the hood when you apply it as a force you need to know that this means 100 horsepower.

Or the engine is simply running at 40%, because the horsepower is completely irrelevant for "Micky's and Donald's Fast Car Championship". Might be different if you play "Realistic Rally Simulator 3000", which is more of a simulation. Call of Duty, Halo, and even CounterStrike have a different goal than being "Realistic Bullet Wound Simulator 3000". You'll notice Arma - which is more of a simulation - does not have a simplified 100 points health bar.

@RaphaelSchmitz The list of games is, quite frankly, completely irrelevant. "Not all games do this" does not mean "this is not sensible" or "this is not worth doing". If you're not interested in answering questions, I don't know why you are in the comments of a question on StackExchange.

OK, look, you're not trying to understand the arguments why it's a bad idea, like even your selected answer tells you. You're only trying to defend that it's a good idea. Nothing anybody says is going to change your mind, so you're just gonna have to learn the hard way; put lots of time and energy into this.
PS For anybody else stumbling upon this and wanting to know more: It's all established game design knowledge - e.g. the book "The Art Of Game Design" by Jesse Schell is pretty good.

As outlined in a comment above, I'm inclined to agree with DavidT that trying to use one root balancing value across a diverse range of games is unlikely to be practical. Even when you allow for each game to adjust those values on import, the amount of one-off adjustment that would need to be made to fit well with the experience of each game is likely to outweigh the benefit of having a standardized input scale in the first place.
That said, if we had to pick some at least plausibly-principled basis for such an input scale, what's the best we could do?
I posed this question to a colleague who used to work in modelling and analyzing the impacts of weapons, explosives, crashes, etc. for the UK Ministry of Defence. They pointed me to Criteria for Incapacitating Soldiers with Fragments and Flechettes, a now-unclassified 1965 report by William Kokinakis and Joseph Sperrazza for the US military. My colleague described this as "the backbone of all military survivability/lethality analysis."
The full report is around 90 pages and too much to summarize well here. Its main approach to quantifying injury is to estimate a probability that a particular hit/wound will incapacitate a soldier, keeping them from performing some tactical role.
It includes formulae and parameter values to compute these probabilities from the projectile's mass and velocity, similar to the kinetic energy formula you gave, with varying degrees of complication depending on the scenario, part of body hit, clothing/armour worn, etc.
You may be able to use this probability as your standard measure of damage. When you need to compute a probability for a scenario not covered in this report, you can search for reports citing it that cover the scenario of interest to you: they should have what you need to convert answer into the same probability terms.
Exactly which number you use will involve some arbitrary choices (e.g. do you assume limb, body, or head shots, or some particular ratio of each? Do you assume a target who's nude, or armoured? At what range? Are they in an assault or defence role? etc...) so unfortunately you'll still have to put your thumb on the scale somewhere when boiling down something as complex as physics tearing through biology into a single number.
Since we ultimately need to make some arbitrary choices anyway, I'd argue in favour of making your arbitrary system as simple as possible. If you can pick a number for a weapon in a couple minutes instead of hours of research, and if a game developer importing your weapon can do so without having to read and understand a 90-page military statistics report, then your proposed system has a better chance of getting wider support. The more technical you make it, the harder it is to create content for or implement into a game. So the arbitrary-unit 0-100 scale has a certain appeal there.

"If you can pick a number for a weapon in a couple minutes instead of hours of research" Once there are some examples to compare against, it will be easier for future assets. If a certain model of gun does X damage, and a user is making a weapon they expect to be 1.5 times as deadly as that model, then they can do 1.5 * X to find the number for their weapon. Anyway, thanks for your answer!

@AaronFranke - The realistic lethality of a weapon is rarely something game designers care about - I recommend watching Design in Detail: Changing the Time Between Shots for the Sniper Rifle from 0.5 to 0.7 Seconds for Halo 3 to get a grasp on how game designers think about weapon balance. If model B is 1.5x as deadly as model A, I expect most game designers would choose to include only one of A and B in their game, and then tune it so that it's balanced with other weapon classes for the experience they're creating.

@TimC: "most game designers would choose to include only one of A and B in their game" - you never encountered a game whose protagonist gets access to a stronger version of the weapon they are wielding in the course of the story?

I don't think it matters if the OP is developing a game themselves, or trying to generate a system/framework to be utilized by games.
In either case, I don't think it is practical to try to apply real world injuries/damage (in a realistic way) to a game context, for the following reasons:

Game Balance - in most games that have a health status, the amount of damage done by weapons, poison, fall damage etc. is a key lever used by the developer to encourage diversity of weapon usage and strategy. For example some games implement a damage fall off, which is unrealistic when compared to the relative damage from a real weapon at various ranges.
Timeline of effect - IRL some weapons and impact location are immediately disabling (instant kill) where as others can still be fatal, but not instantly so (not a doctor) but historically wounds to the lower torso were often fatal, however such wounds did not preclude returning fire for a short period of time. With some exceptions, someone being functional IRL for a minute or two probably doesn't have a huge effect on the overall battle, however given the compressed time lines of a game, it could be significant.
Real world factors - such as fear and pain would accompany a wound, in most cases they would impact the effectiveness of a real world combatant, however the affects are going to be difficult to simulate in a game (the player doesn't really fear for their life).

In summary, I don't think it is possible to create a "a game-agnostic asset standard", since every game will have both different needs and implementation constraints(**) for how damage should be applied in that game.
** - What the devs have time/choose to implement.

Exactly this. Doesn't matter how detailed or realistic a game is, if it's not any fun. Most of those things are already implemented anyway, by having a damage range (e.g. 6-9, where 6 can be interpreted as a graze and 9 as a "good" hit) and critical damage (damage multipliers, x1.5, x2, ...) which can be interpreted as hitting a vital part. Of course you can start doing calculations and simulate angles, armor etc ... but the result is not going to be much different.
